# Magento some product suddenly disappear

Tags: php, magento, caching, redis

We have Magento EE 1.14.0.1. recently we moved to new AWS EC2 server and ElasticCache Redis server.  then some random products start disappearing in the frontend. They exist on backend and configured correctly ( visible , enabled , in stock , etc ....  ). And only after you save the product in backend it will show up again in frontend even without flushing any cache.

- Is this issue related to Redis cache ?
- and if its how to fix it ?

Any input would be appreciated to direct me to a solution.

Thanks

**Update:** I marked everything under Index Management to Update on Save. so I revert that back to update on schedule. and I think that fixed the issue. but still I want to keep my store inventory up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"It's an index issue, every time you update data (product, stock) from database, you have to manually re-index Magento."

That is true for Community Edition, not Enterprise Edition.  In addition, there can be some extra issues when migrating to AWS.  After 4 months of troubleshooting on an inherited server migrated into AWS I found a number of issues/solutions.

**EE issues**
Enterprise Edition indexing is asynchronous for many of the indexes. In addition, not all EE indexes are configured in the typical place. 
On the Admin menu, select System > Configuration. In the panel on the left, under Advanced, select Index Management.
http://docs.magento.com/m1/ee/user_guide/system-operations/index-configuration.html

Even when set to "update on save" in my experience it frequently does not update on save.

**AsyncIndexing was unstable in versions prior to 1.14.3.x .** 
**Upgrade**!  It was possible for the partial process to break in such a way as to make it impossible for indexing to proceed.  One way this will occur is if you are running PHP for the website[typically via PHPFPM] with a different userid and group then you run the cronjobs[shell access].   Indexing depends on the creation of a file to 'lock' the process - the file may only be written/deleted by the user which creates it.

I have found that for performance reasons, it is best to set ALL indexes to "update manually".   Do not schedule a periodic reindex all process, it is useless due to async indexing.  Just make sure your cron is running and everything should be fine.

The AsyncIndex process uses MySQL triggers...which have an issue when trying to migrate a magento database from one server to another.  The way they are created initially, they can ONLY be used by the database user that when the triggers where first created.   If you change the database user for the new server, the triggers will not migrate.  Even worse, there is almost no indication that this occurred and everything except indexing runs perfectly so how can you tell?

Lastly, "reindex all" does not always reindex all.  Thanks to various posts on the internet, I created a shell script to make Magento think all the products were updated and the index needs to be rebuilt:
https://gist.github.com/gamort/5dc5e16bdec00a8bb3b922fc463af17c

**AWS issues**
Using AWS Elasticache Redis has a hidden gotcha - the default zone it is launched in may be different then your server zone.  In my case, the server was in USEAST-1a while Redis defaulted to USEAST-1b.  This resulted in occasional timeouts when looking up data from the cache.  While the website code can usually recover, the indexing code does not.  This leads to the index cron process being in a broken state.

Almost as importantly, you will pay a trivial amount per GB for data transfer from zone 1a to 1b.   But when your cache is working, this "trivial" amount can amount to a lot!  We had a recurring $10+/day [$500-$600 a month] intrazone data transfer fee!   Launch a new redis server in your actual zone, use the redis cli on your web server to make sure you can connect[we had firewall configuration issues] and then only THEN update your configuration.

AWS RDS server also have a hidden gotcha[hope your not too overwhelmed yet].  Migrating the database from another server to Amazon RDS has issues where there was an extremely slight change in what MySQL considers valid SQL for a specific function...which Magento EE just happens to use. :-) .  I ended up installing a new copy of Magento EE and using Navicat to sync the database structures.

**Solr issues**
Suffice to say, there are Solr issues as well.  Mostly due to the schema, but I also found that wiping the solr database and letting it reindex helped.

**Magento Rewrite/Form issues**
This issue occurs when you upgrade to 1.14.3 - which of course you should do since it fixes so many indexing issues.  Version 1.14.3.x added form keys to a number of forms, including the customer sign up form.   So if you created your own custom phtml templates for the logon they will not work!  You need to add that form key field to your customization.   Not a big deal though, since you documented what template file you copied it from initially right?

All in all, I would estimate going through the checklist for migration to be a good 20 hours, and possibly up to 80 depending on what issues you run into.   And at the end of the day, since the fixes are mainly in cron jobs which are not easily visible the website owner will be hard pressed to tell how they benefitted from all that work.  In my case, disappearing products had already been an issue for over a year before we inherited the site the client was understanding about the difficulties.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer. The issue was in magento indexer. I changed everything to Update on Schedule and created a cron job that runs every hour. that took care of all issues. for AWS I had everything on one Oregon region. Since old servers were also in AWS but new region migrated to take advantage of EFS with multiple EC2 :)

Answer (score 0):

It's an index issue, every time you update data (product, stock) from database, you have to manually re-index Magento. If you don't do that, you'll have corrupted data on index and you'll lose SQL join on product request list.

Comment: The issue occurred when I change everything under Index Management to update on save. Does Magento core code has a known bug that miss some products from indexing ?